# HTML Sanitizer for .NET - How to stop it from removing certain tags and forcing valid html

Tags: c#, html-sanitizing

My co-worker introduced the HTML Sanitizer for .NET to our API's. I'm speaking of this one here: https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

He felt it was best to remove dangerous text/scripts from all input - a sort of wall, as you will, to our database. I've noticed a few things that I'd like to stop it from doing:

**1.** Imagine this input: `Stack>;<Overflow`

The Sanitizer will take that and convert it to `Stack&gt;;`

In other words, it takes `<Overflow`, and because it sees the `<` sign (though there's no ending `>` sign) it treats it like a tag that it should remove.  I see that you can configure the Sanitizer with additional "AllowedTags", but it could be anything, not just "Overflow" after the `<` sign.  I can't infinitely add AllowedTags. Can't I get it to just remove tags that are part of a list of dangerous tags, and only remove those?

Of note: `Stack>;< Overflow` (notice the space) becomes `Stack&gt;;&lt; Overflow` -- what we want.  It's the `<Overflow` (with the `O` right up against the `<` sign that causes issues).

**2.** Imagine this input: `Stack>;<b>`

The Sanitizer will take that and convert it to `Stack&gt;;<b></b>`

It sees the `<b>` and wants to add an ending `</b>` to make it valid Html?

But that's not why we want to use this. If the user enters `<b>` (no spaces), we want it to be entered into the database like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are missing an ampersand (`&`) in your problem description. Always expect `>` to be rendered as `&gt;`

Comment: Yes, meant to say `&gt;` and typed `gt;`.  Thanks, I fixed it.  And I do expect it to always be rendered (that's why we HtmlDecode it back before putting it into the database).